# Query con condicional en ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo la siguiente query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
SELECT GRANJA.ID_CENTRO GRANJA_NUMERO,
         T019.DECENTRO GRANJA_DENOMINACION,
         ESTGRANJA.DESCRIPCION GRANJA_ESTADO,
         CICLO.NUMERO CICLO_NUMERO,
         TO_CHAR (CICLO.FECHAINICIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') CICLO_FECHAINICIO,
         TO_CHAR (CICLO.FECHAAPROBACION, 'DD/MM/YYYY') CICLO_FECHAFIN,
         ESTCICLO.DESCRIPCION ESTADO_OPERATIVO_CICLO,
         ESTCIERRE.DESCRIPCION ESTADO_ADMINISTRATIVO_CICLO,  
         BAJADAS.MUERTOS_CAJA_PORC,   
         BAJADAS.DESCARTES_PORC,  
         BAJADAS.SOBRANTE_PORC,    
         BAJADAS.FALTANTE_PORC,    
         BAJADAS.CAJAS_FALTANTES_PORC,     
         BAJADAS.CAJAS_SOBRANTES_PORC,  
         BAJADAS.CANTIDAD_INGRESADO,     
         BAJADAS.ORIGEN_PROPIO_PORC,  
         RECEPFRIGO.RECEPCION_FRIGO_KILOS,
         RECEPFRIGO.RECEPCION_FRIGO_CANTIDAD,
         PKG_GPA_DATO.totalAlimentoConsumidoPorCiclo (CICLO.ID)
            TOTAL_ALIMENTO_CONSUMIDO,
         CASE
            WHEN NVL (CARATULA.ID, 0) = 0
            THEN
                 TRUNC (SYSDATE)
               - TO_DATE (CICLO.FECHAPRIMERABAJADAREAL, 'YYYYMMDD')               
            ELSE
               ROUND (CARATULA.DIASENGORDE)
         END
            CICLO_EDADDIAS,
         CARATULA.CONVERSION,
         (2.1 - CARATULA.CONVERSION) DESVIO_CONVERSION,
         CARATULA.KILOSPROMEDIO PESO_PROMEDIO,
         ROUND (
              PKG_GPA_DATO.totalAlimentoConsumidoPorCiclo (CICLO.ID)
            / RECEPFRIGO.RECEPCION_FRIGO_CANTIDAD,
            2)
            CONSUMO_ALIM_X_AVE,
         CARATULA.EFICIENCIA,
         MORTANDAD.MORTANDAD_CANTIDAD,
         MORTANDAD.MORTANDAD_PORC,
         MORTANDAD.DESVIO_PORC,
         AJUSTECERO.AJUSTECERO,
         ROUND ( (AJUSTECERO * 100) / BAJADAS.CANTIDAD_INGRESADO, 2)
            AJUSTE_CERO_PORC,
         CARATULA.TARIFA TARIFA_X_TABLA,
         CARATULA.TARIFAAPLICAR TARIFA_APLICADA,
         CARATULA.TOTALCOSTOFASON COSTOFASON,         
         T728.ICOSMEDI CPP
    FROM GPA_GRANJA GRANJA
         INNER JOIN T9690190 T019
            ON T019.CGRUEMPR = 1 AND T019.COCENTRO = GRANJA.ID_CENTRO
         INNER JOIN GPA_ESTADO ESTGRANJA ON ESTGRANJA.ID = GRANJA.ID_ESTADO
         LEFT JOIN GPA_CICLO CICLO ON CICLO.ID_GRANJA = GRANJA.ID
         LEFT JOIN GPA_ESTADO ESTCICLO ON ESTCICLO.ID = CICLO.ID_ESTADO
         LEFT JOIN GPA_CIERRE CIERRE ON CIERRE.ID_CICLO = CICLO.ID
         LEFT JOIN GPA_ESTADO ESTCIERRE ON ESTCIERRE.ID = CIERRE.ID_ESTADO
         LEFT JOIN GPA_CIERRECARATULA CARATULA ON CARATULA.ID_CICLO = CICLO.ID AND CARATULA.ACTIVO = 'S'
         LEFT JOIN GPA_CIERRETARIFA TARIFA ON TARIFA.ID_CIERRE = CIERRE.ID
         LEFT JOIN GPA_CIERREESTADO ESTADOCIERRE ON ESTADOCIERRE.ID_CIERRE = CIERRE.ID
         LEFT JOIN
         TCOT7280 T728
            ON     T728.CGRUEMPR = 1
               AND T728.CODCICLO = CICLO.NUMERO
               AND T728.COCENTRO = CICLO.ID_GRANJA
         LEFT JOIN VRECEPFRIGOCICLO RECEPFRIGO
            ON RECEPFRIGO.ID_CICLO = CICLO.ID
         LEFT JOIN VBAJADASCICLO BAJADAS ON BAJADAS.ID_CICLO = CICLO.ID
         LEFT JOIN VAJUSTECEROCICLO AJUSTECERO
            ON AJUSTECERO.ID_CICLO = CICLO.ID
         LEFT JOIN VMORTANDADCICLO MORTANDAD ON MORTANDAD.ID_CICLO = CICLO.ID     
       where ciclo.id > 0
       and (granja.id = :pGranja OR 0 = :pGranja)
       and (ciclo.numero = :NROCICLO OR :NROCICLO = 0)
    )
ORDER BY GRANJA_NUMERO, CICLO_NUMERO
```

A esta query le quiero sumar 4 campos mas de observación pero de diferente perfiles por ejemplo (administrador, gerencia , direccion, etc).

La query correcta para traer esas observaciones es la siguiente (en este caso el perfil esta señalado por el campo CIERREESTADO.ID_ESTADO = 34 )

```
(select CIERREESTADO.Observaciones from gpa_cierre CIERRE
            left join GPA_CICLO CICLO on CICLO.ID = CIERRE.ID_CICLO  
            left join GPA_CIERREESTADO CIERREESTADO ON CIERREESTADO.ID_CIERRE = CIERRE.ID
            where CIERREESTADO.ID_ESTADO = 34 and cierre.id_granja = :granja and ciclo.numero = :ciclo) observaciones_Veterinario
```

Les dejo otro ejemplo con otro perfil

```
(select CIERREESTADO.Observaciones from gpa_cierre CIERRE
        left join GPA_CICLO CICLO on CICLO.ID = CIERRE.ID_CICLO  
        left join GPA_CIERREESTADO CIERREESTADO ON CIERREESTADO.ID_CIERRE = CIERRE.ID
        where CIERREESTADO.ID_ESTADO = 35 and cierre.id_granja = :granja and ciclo.numero = :ciclo) observaciones_Gerencia,
```

El tema es el siguiente las ultimas 2 querys las estoy usando como subconsultas dentro de la query principal, me trae bien los datos siempre y cuando las variables granja y ciclo tengan un valor.
Cuando no le asigno ningún valor a esas variables me debería traer todos los registros con las observaciones correspondientes ya clasificados según el perfil pero en este caso no me trae nada.
**Quisiera saber si habria alguna forma de poder usar estos 2 campos de la query principal**

```
GRANJA.ID_CENTRO GRANJA_NUMERO
CICLO.NUMERO CICLO_NUMERO
```

para que la subconsulta tome como referencia esos valores de la query principal para que me traiga un solo valor único y así me pueda traer todos los registros en una misma línea.
La siguiente imagen es asignándole valores a granja y ciclo así se debería ver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta está difícil de digerir, pero entiendo que básicamente quieres filtrar tu sub-query por valores de la consulta "padre". Esto es posible asignando identificadores de tabla.

Te dejo un ejemplo sin mucho sentido, pero lo suficientemente auto explicativo para que entiendas como se realiza.

**Ejemplo**

```
SELECT
    email,
    (select name from users as users_child where users_child.id = users_parent.id)
FROM 
    users as users_parent;
```

De todas formas vamos a explicar como funciona esto a grandes rasgos...

Supongamos que la tabla `users` tiene lo siguiente

```
id - nombre - email
1  - cesar  - cesar@example.cl
2  - juan   - juan@example.cl
3  - oscar  - oscar@example.cl
```

Cuando ejecutamos la consulta "padre" se traen todos los registros pero uno a uno y, cuando se intenta obtener el campo de la sub-consulta, esta se ejecuta para cada fila que se trae en la consulta padre.

En la consulta y sub-consulta podemos referenciar a cada tabla y campos específicos de cada tabla. Inclusive si estás consultando a la misma tabla (como en el ejemplo) y las mismas columnas, ya que necesitas de un "alias" diferente para cada tabla. Gracias al alias el motor de base de datos sabe como interpretar y comparar correctamente las columnas y sus respectivos valores.

En la practica, para la consulta anterior, si convertimos/traducimos los valores contextuales de cada fila, la sub-consulta se vería algo así.

```
where users_child.id = 1
where users_child.id = 2
where users_child.id = 3
```